# The 'Skip' method is only supported for sorted input in LINQ to Entities. The method 'OrderBy' must be called before the method 'Skip'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, linq-to-entities

And here is the line that is producing the error

```
 var genreModel = storeDB.Categories.Include("Albums").ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize)
.Single(g => g.Name == Category);
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: I assume the `ToPagedList()` extension method is internally appending `Skip()` to the queryable data. Obviously, you need to use `OrderBy()` to use `Skip()`. Also, it's unclear why are you performing paging at all if you're using `Single` in the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I infer that the ToPagedList uses skip and take internally.
Just include an orderBy before it, something like:

```
var genreModel = storeDB.Categories.Include("Albums").OrderBy(x=>x.Id).ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize) .Single(g => g.Name == Category);
```